# How to remove duplicate app entries in GNOME Notifications Settings and in Software?

Tags: apt, gnome, 17.04, gnome-control-center, gnome-software

It's a pretty minor issue, but I'm curious about why it is happening.

In **GNOME Software**, and in *Notifications* in **GNOME Settings**, some system applications appear twice. They don't appear twice in the application list.

For example, Archive Manager and Files are duplicated in Notifications in GNOME Settings.
[image]

Where does GNOME get its application lists from here? Synaptic reports that only one package matching `file-roller` is installed.

Also, `gnome-calendar` is only installed once in Apt, but is duplicated in Software.

[image]

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

> [...] duplicate entries come from multiple .desktop files in /usr/share/applications/

Issue is tracked here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1562409 , it has more detailed information and possible workarounds (e.g. deleting duplicate .desktop files). Just be sure to read all comments thoroughly before deleting anything.